# How to use Metronic 5 bundled libraries in QT

Tags: html, qt, qt-creator, metronic

I am trying to load Metronic's bundled libraries called vendors.bundle.js and scripts.bundle.js to Qt webview html like this.

```
<head>
<script src="qrc:///js/resources/js/vendors.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="qrc:///js/resources/js/scripts.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This is the content of my .qrc:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/js">
        <file>resources/js/scripts.bundle.js</file>
        <file>resources/js/vendors.bundle.js</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

However, I got errors like these after I run in Qt Creator:

Failed to load resource: Error opening :/resources/js/vendors.bundle.js: No such file or directory
Failed to load resource: Error opening :/resources/js/scripts.bundle.js: No such file or directory

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Show the content of the .qrc, it would be very helpful to share your project via github or similar.

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: I have tried it with the parameters that it shows and it works correctly, you could share the complete project through github, drive, dropbox or similar.